# Wordpress: Custom-Field and multiple orderby

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I have defined several custom post types (CPTs) with some Custom Fields (CF) and need to have a certain sorting - first by category, then by date, something along the lines of

```
$args = array (
  'meta_value category' => 'ASC',
  'meta_value startdate' => 'ASC'
  ),
  'post_type' => 'training'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

However, this does not seem to work and the dates are not correctly parsed, since the default parsing of a meta_value is alphabetical. I cannot set the meta_type to DATE, because there are two meta_values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So, I was unable to find a solution. Instead I wrote a custom function in php that took the database result and sorted it to my needs.